# Design of the project implemented in Vivado too complex

Tags: vhdl, router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28bMe.png)This is the second doubt I'm having about this project, consisting in the design and implementation of a syncronous mini - router. I'll share again my source file and my test bench. I tried to simulate on modelsim and thanks to your help, now it works (see the picture).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKd5t.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMWAK.png)

TESTBENCH:

```
-- -------------------------
-- Libreria
-- -------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


-- -------------------------
-- Entity 
-- -------------------------
entity mini_router_tb is   
end mini_router_tb;

-- -------------------------
-- Architecture 
-- -------------------------
architecture arc of mini_router_tb is

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Costanti di testbench 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constant T_CLK      : time := 10 ns; --- frequenza di clock: 100 MHz
     
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Segnali di testbech
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    -- I segnali di input del testbench sono inizializzati per evitare il valore X all'inizio della simulazione
    -- I segnali di outout non sono inizializzati perchè settati dal DUT
    
    signal clk_tb      : std_logic := '0';  -- segnale di clock, inizializzato a 0
    signal reset_tb    : std_logic := '0';  -- reset attivo basso sincrono
    signal data1_tb    : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal req1_tb     : std_logic:= '0'; 
    signal grant1_tb   : std_logic;
    signal data2_tb    : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal req2_tb     : std_logic:= '0'; 
    signal grant2_tb   : std_logic;
    signal data_out_tb : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal valid_tb    : std_logic;
         
    signal end_sim : std_logic := '1'; -- segnale usato per terminare la simulazione quando non c'è più nulla da testare
    
    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Dichiarazione del componente da testare (DUT)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- E' solo una dichiarazione del componente
    -- che sarà instanziato dopo il begin collegando le porte
    -- ai senali di testbench per i test
    component mini_router is
    port (
         clk       : in  std_logic; 
         reset     : in  std_logic; 
         data1     : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
         req1      : in  std_logic; 
         grant1    : out std_logic;
         data2     : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
         req2      : in  std_logic; 
         grant2    : out  std_logic;
         data_out  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
         valid     : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    

begin
    -- Il clock si attiva e disattiva ogni T_CLK / 2 quando end_sim è alto. 
    -- Quando end_sim is è forzato basso, il clock si ferma e la simulazione termina.
    clk_tb  <= (not(clk_tb)and(end_sim)) after T_CLK/2;

   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Mini - Router instantiation
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DUT : mini_router
    port map ( 
        clk      => clk_tb,
        reset    => reset_tb,
        data1    => data1_tb,
        req1     => req1_tb,
        grant1   => grant1_tb,
        data2    => data2_tb,
        req2     => req2_tb,
        grant2   => grant2_tb,
        data_out => data_out_tb,
        valid    => valid_tb
             );

  -- Processo usato per fare in modo che i segnali di testbench signals cambino in corrispondenza del fronte in salita del clock
    stimuli_process: process(clk_tb, reset_tb)
         variable t  : integer   := 0;  -- variabile usata per contare i cicli di clock
         
         begin  
         if (rising_edge(clk_tb)) then 
         
            case (t) is
                
                -- CASO 1:     RESET: gli output sono tutti a 0 indipendentemente dagli input
                   --          data1     = 5; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 5; req2=0
                   --          data_out  = 0; valid=0
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 0; 
            
                when  1     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 3 => '0') & "101"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 4 => '0') & "0101";
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '0';
                               
                -- CASO 2:     UN SOLO REQ ALTO: data1 è propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 4;  req1=1
                   --          data2     = 13; req2=0
                   --          data_out  = 1; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 1; 
                   --          grant2 = 0;             
                               
                when  2     => reset_tb  <= '1';  
                               data1_tb  <= (9 downto 3 => '0') & "100"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 4 => '0') & "1101";
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '0';
                               
                -- CASO 3:     UN SOLO REQ ALTO: data2 è propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 4;  req1=0
                   --          data2     = 13; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 3; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 1;  
                               
                             
                when  3     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 3 => '0') & "100"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 4 => '0') & "1101";
                               req1_tb   <= '0' ; req2_tb<= '1';
                               
                -- CASO 4:     REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E STESSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data conflict e applicazione dell'algoritmo Round Robin:
                --             data1 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 7;  req1=1
                   --          data2     = 31; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 1; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 1; 
                   --          grant2 = 0;  
                               
                             
                when  4     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "00111"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11111";  
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '1';
                               
                -- CASO 5:     REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E DIVERSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data1 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 23; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 29; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 5; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 1; 
                   --          grant2 = 0;  
                               
                                
                when  5     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "10111"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11101";  
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '1';
                               
                -- CASO 6:     REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E STESSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data conflict e applicazione dell'algoritmo Round Robin:
                --             data2 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 22; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 30; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 7; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 1;  
                             
                when 6      => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "10110"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11110"; 
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '1';    
                               
                -- CASO 7:     REQ ENTRAMBI BASSI: nessun dato è propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 7;  req1=0
                   --          data2     = 31; req2=0
                   --          data_out  = 0; valid=0
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 0; 
                               
                                
                when 7      => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "00111"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11111"; 
                               req1_tb   <= '0' ; req2_tb<= '0';

                -- CASO 8:     REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E DIVERSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data2 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 28; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 13; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 3; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 1;                 
                               
                            
                when  8     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11100"; 
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 4 => '0') & "1101"; 
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb <= '1';
                               
                -- CASO 9:     REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E STESSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data conflict e applicazione dell'algoritmo Round Robin:
                --             data1 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 22; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 30; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 5; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 1; 
                   --          grant2 = 0; 
                               
                 
                when 9      => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "10110"; --data1=22; data_out =5
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11110"; -- data2= 30; data_out non assunto=7
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '1';
                               
                -- CASO 10:    REQ ENTRAMBI ALTI E STESSO LIVELLO DI PRIORITA':
                --             data conflict e applicazione dell'algoritmo Round Robin:
                --             data2 propagato in uscita
                   --          data1     = 22; req1=1
                   --          data2     = 30; req2=1
                   --          data_out  = 7; valid=1
                   --          grant1 = 0; 
                   --          grant2 = 1; 
                               
                
                when 10     => data1_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "10110"; --data1=22; data_out non assunto =5
                               data2_tb  <= (9 downto 5 => '0') & "11110"; -- data2= 30; data_out =7
                               req1_tb   <= '1' ; req2_tb<= '1';
                               
                                            
                when 11     => end_sim   <= '0'; -- La simulazione termina quando t=10.
                
                when others => null; -- Si specifica che nulla accade negli altri casi.
                         
            end case;

            t := t + 1;
        
          end if;           
     end process;
end architecture;
                
                                
           



SOURCE FILE:
- -------------------------
-- Libreria
-- -------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


-- -------------------------
-- Entity 
-- -------------------------
entity mini_router is
   port (
         clk       : in  std_logic; 
         reset     : in  std_logic; -- Reset asincrono attivo basso
         data1     : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
         req1      : in  std_logic; 
         grant1    : out std_logic;
         data2     : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
         req2      : in  std_logic; 
         grant2    : out std_logic;
         data_out  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
         valid     : out std_logic
        );
  end entity;
  
  
-- -------------------------
-- Architecture 
-- -------------------------    
architecture arch of mini_router is  
  
  signal aux        : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 
  
 begin
 mini_router: process(clk,reset)
  
  variable r : std_logic:= '1'; 
  
  begin
   if reset = '0' then
       aux     <= (others => '0');
       grant1  <= '0';
       grant2  <= '0';
       valid   <= '0';
       
       
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then
 
 
    if (req1 xor req2) = '1' then 
  
     if req1 = '1' then 
        aux    <= data1;
        grant1 <= '1';
        grant2 <= '0';
        valid  <= '1';
        
     else 
        aux    <= data2;
        grant1 <= '0';
        grant2 <= '1';
        valid  <= '1';
     end if;

  
 
   elsif (req1 and req2) = '1'  then  

     if (unsigned(data1 (1 downto 0))) > (unsigned(data2 (1 downto 0))) then
       aux    <= data1;
       grant1 <= '1';
       grant2 <= '0';
       valid  <= '1';
            
     elsif (unsigned(data1 (1 downto 0))) < (unsigned(data2 (1 downto 0))) then
      aux      <= data2;
      grant1  <= '0';
      grant2  <= '1';
      valid   <= '1';
 
     elsif (unsigned(data1 (1 downto 0))) = (unsigned(data2 (1 downto 0))) then  

       if r = '1' then 
          aux    <= data1;
          grant1 <= '1';
          grant2 <= '0';
          valid  <= '1';
          r := not (r);
  
       else 
          aux    <= data2;
          grant1 <= '0';
          grant2 <= '1';
          valid  <= '1';
          r := not (r);
        end if;

     end if;


     elsif (req1 nor req2) = '1'  then
        aux     <= (others => '0');
        grant1  <= '0';
        grant2  <= '0';
        valid   <=  '0';      
      
      end if; 
    
    end if; 
   
 end process;
  
      data_out <= aux(9 downto 2);

end architecture;
```

But then I tried to simulate and implement it in Xilinx Vivado. There were no warnings, so I think everything work well, but as you can see from the picture, the structure is really too complicated and (I think) not efficient. My doubt is: is the problem the fact that I use only if/else/eslsif for my code, without a component instantion? I looked for another possibile design for my project, but this I the only solution I could come up with. Have you got any suggestions for me?

Comment: This is not really a valid question. If you have no problems, then what's the problem. Your question is asking for opinion, which means it is not a very good question.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you think, your code is not efficient? In my opinion, the schematic does not give a hint in this direction.
But there are some items which could be improved:
You define a variable r (with an initialization value) which is used as a signal (first read and then written), so you should it define as a signal (with a reset value). You should use variables only, if the behavior cannot be modeled by a signal.
Aux(1 downto 0) are never used, so you should not define them.
Your structure is a deep if-elsif-else structure, as if there was a priority which has to be used for the checks. But there is no priority for the check of req1 and req2?!
A deep structure often causes bad timing in the way that you get long combinatorial paths through many components. You can check this by looking at a timing report of your design.
So I would create a signal “request <= req1 & req2” and then use a “case” construct for all the decisions.
For the check of data1/2(1 downto 0) I would create this signal in a combinatorial process:
'''

```
process (data1, data2, r)
begin
if (unsigned(data1 (1 downto 0))) > (unsigned(data2 (1 downto 0))) then
       prio    <= "00";
elsif (unsigned(data1 (1 downto 0))) < (unsigned(data2 (1 downto 0))) then
      prio     <= "01";
else
      prio  <= '1' & r;
end process;
```

'''
So again you could switch to a case statement.
After these changes you could look at the timing report again. As your design is small, it may be that the synthesis tool has the same ideas and did all of the improvements automatically. But at least your design would be easier to read and give a hint, that there is no priority for the checks you have implemented.

Comment: Where should I put this : process (data1, data2, r)? Inside my main process :mini_router: process(clk,reset)? I don't know how to use my clock ad reset signals

Comment: Please put it outside your main process as a second process.

Comment: But the two 'case' to add ( the first for request and the second for prio), must be inside a process right? Where should I put them? I'm sorry, I undestrand your answer, but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: put the case-constructs in your main clocked process.